# Had I better to reserve memory for my process?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

I wrote a program that manipulates with files. In the idle state, the memory occupied by the process is ~ 60 MBs. Periodically, say every 2 minutes, the process allocates memory (~ 40 MBs), performs something with files, then frees the allocated memory. The procedure takes around 10 ~ 20 seconds. As the result, the memory usage of my process looks like in the below picture:

[image: Memory usage with pulses]

My question here is: should I reserve some memory in advance then use the memory when I need? This would make memory usage trend more stable. **And the stability would be better for system, am I right?**

Comment: just out of curiosity: Why are you worried about the memory usage trend?

Comment: It is unlikely that allocating and freeing ~40MB of RAM would take more than a few miliseconds at most and would likely not improve your performance by any measurable amount. What are you hoping to achieve by doing so?

Comment: @tobi303 I mean is the memory usage with pulses good for OS?

Comment: @Rotem First I allocate memory (~40 MBs) and uses the memory as a buffer to manipulate with files. It usually takes ~20 seconds (or more) to complete processing files.

Comment: @duong_dajgja That is clear, which is why I don't understand your goal in pre-allocating memory. What would it achieve? Why not let the OS enjoy an additional 40MB when you're not using them.

Comment: @Rotem I updated the question to clarify what I wanna know.

Comment: Not an expert but unless it provides needed and measurable performance benefits then I would think you should give as much memory back to the system as possible so that all the other programs have potential access to it. If every program acted greedy I suspect that might be the larger drag on the system as a whole.

Comment: I think more than memory, the file operations might be time consuming. If you can show what are you doing with files then things can be sorted out.

Comment: usually memory that you allocate in your code does not directly correspond to the amount of memory usage you see in the task manager. Actually I am a bit surprised about these kinks. It could as well be that the OS only frees the memory when your program finishes. I would not pay too much attention on what you see in the task manager, but if you really want to study memory usage of your program you could use other diagnostic tools.

Answer (score 0):

No, any 21st century OS won't blink an eye if you do this. Things might get interesting if you try to allocate more than 4GB per millisecond across 100 CPU cores, but you're not even close to that.

Comment: 100 CPU cores? I want your computer.

Answer (score -1):

If you allocate memory in advance say additional 50MB as you say the graph would be a straight line (i.e. stable) but programs competing for memory might not get enough and they would suffer due to it.